# how notepad++ picture extended chars

Tags: ascii, notepad++, text-editor, extended-ascii

I'm working with binary data and want to find out that is wrong.

I use notepad++ to preview binary, I have set `View->Show Symbol->Show All Characters` to see all chars, but there still exists some chars I cannot identify, e.g. `â©ÎÅ`. The problem is that ASCII has strong standart for number 0 to 127, extended ASCII may be picturing in many ways, so I have problem with chars what represents numbers 128 to 255.

Is there any table of notepad++ extended chars or some option to make it show symbol code instead of symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not solution for you, but in PSPad and SynWrite editors you can:

- create text-converter (INI file) which changes ASCII 127..255 to strings like `<127>`...`<255>` or others
- apply this converter to text.

Text converter usage is described in help of both apps.