# Saving a document encoded in extended ASCII in Notepad++

Tags: encoding, ascii, notepad++, extended-ascii

I would like to know how to save a document using Notepad++ encoded in extended ASCII. When I select ANSI encoding, it is saved as UTF-8 codification (I checked it in HxD, program to see hex data file).

Comment: What about workaround? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352595/how-notepad-picture-extended-chars Check http://superuser.com/questions/558781/show-hexadecimal-ascii-codes-on-notepad-6-3 also

Comment: There is more than one extension to ASCII. Please tell me what encoding you want. Also, this question is off-topic and belongs to Super User instead.

Comment: I only want to parse UTF-8 encoding to extended ASCII encoding using Notepad++

Comment: "Extended ASCII" is kind of meaningless. You need to know which actual codepage you want

Comment: I want to parse this encoding (http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) to this one  (http://www.elcodigoascii.com.ar/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with Notepad++. The best way is to paste your text into Wordpad and then save as MS-DOS text format.